# How to manage OAuth token requests for a POS system in a Flutter app using Firebase with Google, Apple, and Email authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase, oauth-2.0

I am building a Flutter application for a coffee shop and I need suggestions on how to best architect my Flutter app. I am using Firebase for the backend of my app and I am storing additional information about each user in a collection called users. I am also calling an API endpoint to register the user within their POS system. The coffee shop POS stores information like loyalty points and other additional useful user-specific information. However, in order to access this useful information to display on my UI you need an OAuth token for the user that can be retrieved by hitting an API endpoint. The problem is that in order to make this OAuth token request you need the user's email and password. I currently have Google, Apple, and email authentication enabled. Firebase does not allow you to directly grab the user's password which is making it difficult for me to make the OAuth token request. An important note is that once you successfully hit the OAuth token endpoint it gives you a refresh token. I have a few suggestions of my own which are:

1. Have a password field within the user document and use a cloud function to encrypt the password.
2. Once the user first registers (ask Google/Apple auth to enter password), make the OAuth request and store the refresh token as a field within the user document. (I'll have to ask the POS how long the refresh token exists, but for now, I am going to assume it does not expire).
3. Use a default password for each user within the POS (I don't think this is the way to go).

I would appreciate any advice/expand on my suggestions/make new suggestions if you can think of any.